# SQL SP Iterate Algorithm

Tags: sql

I need a little help with my Stored Procedure.

I would like to iterate through a set of columns from a result and take each value and look up a corresponding value and then add all those together.

The only way I can see of doing it, is by using separate variables for each week position and each weeks scores plus separate select statements. Can anyone help me? This obviously isn't good for scalibility.

Store Procedure

> ```
>  @pName varchar(50) = ''
> AS
> BEGIN
>
>
>   Declare @p1 int = 0
>   Declare @p2 int = 0
>   Declare @s1 int = 0
>   Declare @s2 int = 0
>   Declare @pUserID int = 0
>   Declare @pTotal int = 0
>
>
>   set @pUserID = (Select UserID from PKR_USERS where UserName = @pName)
>
>   set @p1 = (Select WEEK1POS From PKR_TOURNAMENT12)
>   set @p2 = (Select WEEK2POS From PKR_TOURNAMENT12)
>
>   set @s1  = (Select Points from PKR_SCORING where Position = @p1)
>   set @s2  = (Select Points from PKR_SCORING where Position = @p2)
>
>   set @pTotal = @s1 + @s2
>
>   Update PKR_RESULTS set points = @pTotal Where UserID =  @pUserID
> END
> ```

```
> PKR_Tournament12 Table 
> 
> [USERID][WEEK1POS][WEEK2POS] 1    1   1
```

> PKR_Scoring Table
>
> [Position][Points] 1  10 2    9

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this  i used UNPIVOT     pls test it

```
Declare @pTotal int = ISNULL(
  SELECT SUM(ISNULL(Points)) FROM PKR_SCORING where Position  IN (
   SELECT FieldValue
FROM
(
  SELECT 
     WEEK1POS ,
     WEEK2POS 
  FROM dbo.PKR_TOURNAMENT12 WHERE USERID=(Select UserID from PKR_USERS where UserName = @pName)
) MyTable
 UNPIVOT
(FieldValue FOR FieldCode IN (WEEK1POS, WEEK2POS))AS MyUnPivot),0)
Update PKR_RESULTS set points = @pTotal Where UserID =  @pUserID
```